# Triple boot windows 8.1, win 7 and ubuntu (or other distro)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot, grub

I'm trying to install ubuntu, my laptop HDD configuration as follow:

- Reserved drive (350MB) to boot Win 8.1
- Win 8.1
- Win 7
- Unallocated space (i deleted a drive to have a space for ubuntu)

My main window is **Win 8.1 (installed first)**, then i installed Win7. The problem when i try to install ubuntu (or any linux distro) i'm stuck to choose **which drive to use for bootloader installation** since i **only have a 350MB drive to boot win 8.1** and almost all the tutorial i read was mentioning an (**100MB efi drive**)  "see the image below".

[image]

So how i could install ubuntu (or any linux distro) without having a boot issues with the other OS.

*Note: I'm actually using VMware workstation 11, but i prefer if i could install without a VM.*

Comment: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported